# Mongo DB Class Refactoring

Tags: c#, mongodb

What would be the best way to override the Mongo Serializer for the following scenario:

I have the following class

```
public Class Quest
{
   public ObjectId _id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<string> GalleryImagePaths {get; set;}
}
```

After a refactoring exercise the GalleryImagePaths property is refactored to a

```
public List<HttpFile> GalleryImagePaths {get; set;}

public Class HttpFile 
{
  string FilePath {get; set;}
  string UriPath {get; set;}
}
```

Now the default serializer can't deserialize to

```
List<string> GalleryImagePaths
```

And the new data documents will be stored in the new schema.

What is best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

[`BsonSerializer`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_BsonSerializer.htm) class is static and uninheritable so I think a custom serializer would help serialization/deserialization in this case.

For example:

```
using System.Reflection;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

// Custom Serializer
public static class MyBsonSerializer
{
    public static Quest DeserializeQuest(BsonDocument bson)
    {
        Quest quest = new Quest();
        var properties = typeof(Quest).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();

        foreach (var element in bson.Elements)
        {
            switch (element.Name)
            {
                case "GalleryImagePaths":
                    List<HttpFile> paths = new List<HttpFile>();
                    foreach (var path in element.Value.AsBsonArray)
                    {
                        var httpFile = new HttpFile();
                        // Set FilePath and UriPath
                        paths.Add(httpFile);
                    }
                    quest.GalleryImagePaths = paths;
                    break;
                case "_id":
                    properties.First(p => p.Name == element.Name).SetValue(quest, new ObjectId(element.Value.ToString()));
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    properties.First(p => p.Name == element.Name).SetValue(quest, element.Value.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return quest;
    }

    public static BsonDocument SerializeQuest(Quest quest)
    {
        BsonDocument bson = new BsonDocument();
        bson.Add(new BsonElement("Name", quest.Name));
        var paths = quest.GalleryImagePaths.Select(h => h.UriPath); 
        // OR quest.GalleryImagePaths.Select(h => h.FilePath)
        bson.Add(new BsonElement("GalleryImagePaths", new BsonArray(paths)));

        return bson;
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Quest");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", "sample");
Quest quest = MyBsonSerializer.DeserializeQuest(collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault());
```

Serialization (and Insert):

```
collection.InsertOne(MyBsonSerializer.SerializeQuest(quest));
```